# Create String array in Objective C

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a String array and trying to use below code. This create array with garbage data. Can anyone explain me why is it so?

NSString *str[2];

str[0] = @"Welcome";

Comment: Really, if youcan't do this, you shouldn't do iOS development, you'll damage the system one day...

Comment: Come on, everyone has to start somehow! Sumit should google before asking on SO though, or better get an iOS book.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

**--- iOS 7 Update ---**

iOS 7 SDK now publicly exposes a `firstObject` method on arrays which will not throw an out of bounds exception if the array is empty. It can be used as such:

```
NSString *str = [array firstObject];
if(str != nil){
  // Your code here
}else{
  // Array was empty
}
```